# The error of my Javascript function which supposed to return the length of an array if an array is given and return zero otherwise

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know much programming and I'm learning Javascript for a couple of days now so my question might be very easy, apologize in advance:

The question is:

> Create a function named 'arrayCounter' that takes in a parameter which is an array. The function must return the length of an array passed in or 0 if a 'string', 'number' or 'undefined' value is passed in.

And I've done this:

```
function arrayCounter(i) {
    var no = ['string', 'undefined', 'number'];
    for (j = 0; j < no.length; j += 1) {
      if(typeof(i) === no[j]) {return 0}
    }
    return i.length
```

Why my code is wrong?

Comment: Is this homework?  Also, where is your function's closing bracket?

Comment: Why do you think your code is wrong? What problem are you experiencing? Please don't just post your code, **explain** your problem.

Comment: No, it's for Teamtreehouse.com (http://teamtreehouse.com/library/javascript-foundations#arrays). The first exercise for functions. 
The reason I'm asking here is that their forum is not sufficiently active and the previous topic on this issue has not been resolved for nearly 9 months.

Comment: well one thing can be optimized. you know the length of var no, so there is no need to calculate length three times

Comment: `function arrayCounter(i) {return Array.isArray(i) ? i.length : 0};`

Comment: @FelixKling because neither the teamtreehouse website nor an ide like (http://js.do/) accepts it.

Comment: What does "accept" mean this context? Read these articles to [learn](http://juliepagano.com/blog/2014/05/18/javascript-debugging-for-beginners) [how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging), so you can provide more useful context information (and help yourself). If I put your code into js.do, I see a big red box saying `JavaScript error: SyntaxError: missing } after function body on line 11`. Do you understand the error message?

Comment: @user272651 Where is your function's closing bracket?

Comment: @FelixKling Thank you for the article; What I saw on js.do was Unexpected token ) on line 4 . This was the reason I posted this question since I couldn't figure out the problem with the parenthesis; adding a closing bracket fixes the problem though and now I can't regenerate the error when I intentionally delete the closing bracket!

Answer (score 0):

You should make use of JavaScript's `Array.isArray(arg)` function, which tells if you some provided argument `arg` is an array. Using this function, we will check to see if the argument `i` passed to your function `arrayCounter` is an array. If it is, we return its `length`. Otherwise, we return `0`, like such:

```
function arrayCounter(i) {
    // if the argument is an array, return its length
    if (Array.isArray(i)) {
        return i.length;
    }
    // otherwise, return zero
    else {
        return 0;
    }
};
```

If you want your code to be slightly less readable but a bit more concise, you can use JavaScript's conditional ternary operator, like such (as alluded to by @adeneo above):

```
function arrayCounter(i) {
    return (Array.isArray(i) ? i.length : 0);
};
```